# Dynamic programming problem for minimum cost tower placement

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, computer-science

I have an algorithmic problem in which I have a highway that is a straight line of length n and a set of unique respective costs for construction of a radio tower for each mile on the highway. I am trying to use dynamic programming to find a way to minimize the cost of ensuring that each point in the highway is covered by at least one tower.
I am given a length n for the highway, an array of costs of length n + 1, and must assume that the towers all will have a 5 mile range (eg a tower built at point i will have range [i-5,i+5] inclusive).

I believe that my subproblem is OPT(i) where i is the minimum cost to cover the first i miles of highway, however am having trouble constructing my recursive formula or algorithm. I know that a greedy approach would not be optimal in this case.
I think that perhaps the shortest path problem could be harnessed however am having trouble creating an answer that follows the steps of dynamic programming.
So far this is my algorithm:

1. Initialize an array C of length n+1, where C[i] represents the minimum cost to cover the first i miles of the highway.
2. Set C[0] = 0 and C[1] = cost[1].
3. For i = 2 to n, calculate C[i] using the recurrence relation:
   C[i] = min(cost[i] + C[i-5], C[i-1])
4. Return C[n], which represents the minimum cost to cover the entire highway.
   Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You should post this to Coputer Science Stack exchange network. This is not the place where you do it.

Comment: @NeerajRoy we like these questions just fine under the algorithm tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the placement of a tower in cell i is valid if it, together with all previously placed towers, covers all cells <= i+5. Since the range within 5 is covered by the tower at i, we can place a tower there if every cell from 0 up to i-6 is covered.

In your DP array, the value in cell i is the min total cost a valid placement of a tower in cell i.

Then, DP[i] = C[i] + min(DP[j]) for all j that cover i - range - 1 (the closest tower to the left not covered by tower i).

At the end, the answer is the minimum value of DP[i] for all the i that cover the last cell.

The tower that covers cell i can be placed in any of the 11 spots between i-5 and i+5.

I'll give a smaller example -- same concept, but each tower covers cells within 2.

input: [16, 4, 8, 12, 7, 5, 11, 12, 14, 3]

We fill out the DP array as follows:

```
index: value & reasoning
0: 16 (no previous towers not covered by this)
1:  4 (no previous towers not covered by this)
2:  8 (no previous towers not covered by this)
3: 12 + min(16,  4,  8)         = 12 + 4 = 16
4:  7 + min(16,  4,  8, 16)     =  7 + 4 = 11
5:  5 + min(16,  4,  8, 16, 11) =  5 + 4 =  9    
6: 11 + min( 4,  8, 16, 11,  9) = 11 + 4 = 15
7: 12 + min( 8, 16, 11,  9, 15) = 12 + 8 = 20
8: 14 + min(16, 11,  9, 15, 20) = 14 + 9 = 23
9:  3 + min(11,  9, 15, 20, 23) =  3 + 9 = 12
```

Any of the last 3 cover the last spot, so the answer is min(20, 23, 12) = 12.

By tracking which mins are selected each time, we can find the selection of towers that gives us the min.

```
index 9: min comes from index 5
index 5: min comes from index 1
index 1: min comes from a negative index so we're done
```

12 comes from indices 1, 5, 9

[16, (4), 8, 12, 7, (5), 11, 12, 14, (3)]

Ruby code (read as pseudocode if you don't know Ruby)

```
def f(costs, range)
  # the first range elements of dp are identical to costs since they don't depend on a prior tower
  dp = costs[0, range + 1]
  
  # now, for each new index, we need to add the smallest previous dp sum 
  # associated with a tower that covers the spot range-1 to the left.
  (range + 1).upto(costs.length - 1) do |i|
    left_indx_of_subrange = [0, i - (2*range + 1)].max
    right_indx_of_subrange = i-1
    length_of_subrange = right_indx_of_subrange - left_indx_of_subrange + 1
    dp[i] = costs[i] + dp[left_indx_of_subrange, length_of_subrange].min
  end
  puts dp.to_s
  return dp[-(range + 1), range + 1].min
end

> f([16, 4, 8, 12, 7, 5, 11, 12, 14, 3], 2)
=> 12
```

This code doesn't track which indices were used.

Range 5 example:

```
cost = [47, 30, 38, 18, 10, 26, 16, 33, 42, 13, 29, 34, 25, 35, 30, 38, 15, 15, 45, 18, 28, 19, 37, 20, 20, 12, 29, 40, 13, 30, 24, 35, 44, 38, 24, 26, 22, 46, 39, 10, 27, 40, 36, 25, 36, 40, 26, 42, 49, 12]
range = 5
optimal = 73
optimal selections in parens: [47, 30, 38, 18, (10), 26, 16, 33, 42, (13), 29, 34, 25, 35, 30, 38, 15, (15), 45, 18, 28, 19, 37, 20, 20, 12, 29, 40, (13), 30, 24, 35, 44, 38, 24, 26, 22,  46, 39, (10), 27,  40,  36, 25,  36, 40,  26,  42,  49, (12)]
DP array: [47, 30, 38, 18, 10, 26, 26, 43, 52, 23, 39, 44, 35, 45, 40, 48, 38, 38, 68, 41, 51, 54, 72, 55, 58, 50, 67, 78, 51, 71, 65, 85, 94, 88, 74, 76, 72, 97, 90, 61, 88, 101, 97, 86, 97, 101, 87, 103, 110, 73]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the needed dynamic programming formulation in terms of an example. I believe the algorithm is essentially the same as @Dave's.

**Data for example problem**

Suppose

```
n = 10
r = 3 
c = [2, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4]
```

where `r` equals the radius of tower coverage, in miles, and `c[d]` equals the cost of building a tower at location d miles from the origin, `d = 0, 1,..., n`.

**Assumptions and definitions**

A tower built at distance `d` from the origin covers an area from distance `max {0, d-r}` to distance `min { d+r, n}`.

A collection of towers built at intregal-valued locations between `0` and `d`, `d <= n`, is considered *feasible* relative to `d` if all points between `0` and `d` are covered by at least one tower.

At location `d, d = 0,1,...,n` let `x(d)` equal the minimum cost among all feasible tower construction projects relative to `d` when the last tower is built at distance `d`. These are the model's *state variables*.

**Work forward to determine optimal costs of partial solutions**

When `d = 0, 1, 2, 3`, `x(d)` is simply the cost of constructing the tower since a tower at any of those locations will cover the area between `0` and `3`. Therefore,

```
x(0)  = c[0] = 2, save p = nil
x(1)  = c[1] = 4, save p = nil 
x(2)  = c[2] = 6, save p = nil
x(3)  = c[3] = 5, save p = nil
```

For the moment, disregard the references `save p = nil`.

At `d = 4` things change, because building a tower at `d = 4` does not cover the area between `d = 0` and `d = 1`. A tower therefore must be built at `d` equal to `1`, `2`, or `3`. We therefore compute

```
x(4) = c[4] + min {x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3)} =
     =   4  + min {2, 4, 6, 5}
     =   6
save p = 0
```

We set `p = 1` to indicate that distance at which the previous tower would be built. This information is used later to reconstruct the optimal solution.

The calculations for `d = 5,..., 10` are similar.

```
x(5) = c[5] + min {x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)} =
         3  + min {  2,    4,    6,    5,    6}
     = 5
save p = 0

x(6) = c[6] + min {x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5)}
     =   5 + min {   2,    4,    6,    5,    6,    5}
     = 7
save p = 0

x(7) = c[7] + min {X(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6)}
     =   4  + min {  4,    6,    5,    6,    5,    7 }
     =   8
save p = 1

x(8) = c[8] + min {x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7)}
     =   3  + min {  6,    5,    6,    5,    7,    8 }
     =   8
save p = 3 (or could save p = 5)

x(9) = c[9] + min {x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7), x(8)}
     =   2  + min {  5,    6,    5,    7,    8,    8 }
     =   7
save p = 3
```

Lastly, for the endpoint at distance `n` (10),

```
x(10) = c[10] + min {x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7), x(8), x(9)}
      =   4   + min {  6,    5,    7,    8,    8,    7 }
      =   9
save p = 5
```

**Compute the optimal value**

The given radius implies that the last project must be at distance `7`, `8`, `9` or `10`. We therefore compute:

```
min {x(7), x(8), x(9), x(10)} = min {8, 8, 7, 9} = 7
```

**Reconstruct the optimal solution**

We will use the values of `p` that we saved to reconstruct the optimal solution. We just determined that the last tower built in the optimal solution was at `d = 9`.

If we examine the calculation of `x(9)` we see that we set `p = 3`, meaning that the previous tower would be built at distance `3`.

In computing `x(3)` we saved `p = nil`, which signified the first tower was built at that distance (`3`).

We therefore have determined that in the optimal solution towers are built at distances of `3` and `9`, and that the optimal value is `7`, the total cost of building towers at those two locations. We can check that.

```
c[3] + c[9] = 5 + 2 = 7
```

Comment: @user3386109, many thanks for demonstrating that my answer was incorrect. I believe that it is now correct but do let me know if you spot any more problems. Note that in reworking my answer I changed `c[10]` from `1` to `4`. As a result none of the optimal solutions include a tower at distance `10`.

Comment: @user3386109, recall that in my example the radius, `r`, equals `3`, so a tower at `0` would cover from `0` to `3` on the highway and the tower at `7` would cover from `4` to `10` on the highway, leaving the area between `3` and `4` uncovered, so that is not a feasible solution.

Comment: @user3386109, it makes no difference which interpretation is correct as one can simply adjust the algorithm in an obvious way to fit the interpretation.